# Raspberry Pi GPIO control in electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have created a simple app that can control the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi with a simple button press. However, when I press the button, there is no response from the GPIO pins (here connected to GPIO 24). Also, I have already installed the onoff module from `npm install onoff`. When I create a simple javascript file with only GPIO control and run `node <file_name>.js`, it runs successfully. But when I try to integrate into electron, it stops working. Please check the following code. Help would be appreciated.

##### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>GPIO Control</h1>
        <button id="Btn" class="button is-primary">LED ON</button>
        <script src="./render.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

##### main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

##### render.js

```js
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio; 
var LED = new Gpio(24, 'out');

const Btn = document.getElementById("Btn");
Btn.onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  LED.writeSync(1);
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe share some more details (by [edit]ing your question) as to what goes wrong? "It stops working" is not particularly helpful... Any errors in the Browser's DevTools? Have you encountered any errors when installing the module or running the Electron app? Thanks!

Comment: Your code with GUI stuff is a bit too complicated.  I would suggest to try the following two newbie getting started toy code first: (1) led.write, (2) button.watch. Ref: OnOff [LED and Buttons] - Node.js v16 GPIO access and interrupt detection with Node.js on Linux boards like the Raspberry Pi, ... - 2021apr
https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff. Cheers.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?